# lack of identity between jQuery selector and jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a maddening problem where I set a variable to point to a jQuery selector, such as: `var foobar=jQuery(this);` I then pass this variable to a function to be worked on. Let's simplify a little and say the function looks like this:

```
function SetFieldValue (selector) {
  selector.val('test');
  console.log ( selector );
  console.log ( jQuery('#' + selector.attr('id')) );
}
```

In this situation if you assume that:

- the selector is always a form element (and therefore val() is a valid operation)
- the selector does resolve to a single dom element which has an 'id' attribute

You would then expect the two console.log statements to output the same result, right? Well I'm running into a situation where this condition only happens about 90% of the time.

In order to give more context I've created a short screencast demonstrating the problem:

[SCREENCAST LINK](https://vimeo.com/54845255)

For reference purposes, here's the actual SetFieldValue code that is shown in the screencast:

```
function SetFieldValue ( domObject, value ) {
// as a safety function, check if a string representation of the domObject was passed in and convert it to a jQuery object if it was
if ( jQuery.type(domObject) === "string") {
    console.log ("Value passed into SetFieldValue was a string representation so converting to jQuery object");
    domObject = jQuery(domObject);
}

if ( jQuery.inArray (domObject.prop('tagName').toLowerCase(),['input' , 'select' , 'textarea']) >= 0 ) {
    console.log ("setting to value attribute: " + value);
    if ( domObject.hasAttr('id') ) {
        domObject.val(value);
        //jQuery('#' + domObject.attr('id')).val(value);
    } else {
        domObject.attr('value',value);          
    }

    console.log ("Using jQuery ID it is set to: " + jQuery('#' + domObject.attr('id')).val() );
    console.log ("Using jQuery selector variable it is set to: " + domObject.val() );
} else {
    console.log ("setting to html attribute");
    domObject.html( value );
}
return domObject;
}
```

Comment: Is the ID unique in the page? If not, `$('#id')` returns the first element with that ID. Also, in theory, `selector` might not be in the DOM: `SetFieldValue($('<input id="notInDomElement"></input>'))`.

Comment: Also, your video is private, and cannot be opened. I'd recommend against videos anyway. Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsbin.com/ ?

Comment: The ID is unique on the page. As for the video, I did it because I felt recreating the code in an open environment would be too hard. Just out of interest, why do you think videos aren't a good idea?

Comment: Can you give us a specific instance of some HTML and the function not working as you expect, perhaps at jsfiddle.net?  I see some potential problems, but nothing conclusive.

Comment: As for videos: They are very cumbersome to watch, cannot be debugged, we cannot copy code from them (or search it), and usually they do not encourage research, as opposed to a small example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Kobi, makes sense. That is what I normally do but as this one is so inexplicable to me I just don't know how to recreate it. I have openned up the video now.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, the problem is largely an interaction between the SetFieldValue function listed and obviously some context around what the "domObject" is which is intended to described above. If you don't mind looking at the screencast I think it will make sense. I do appreciate that code (not video) is the best way to address these things but I am struggling to create the effect in a sandbox and hoped the video would work as a substitute.

Comment: I have created a simple recreation on JSFiddle but it WORKS. :^( You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ksnyde/pMJaf/6/ . I guess my question is how is it possible this WOULDN'T work. The video demonstrates this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Lets examine the code a bit.

First assigning back to a parameter is not a good practice adding a var at the start of your function would be a lot better, as scope can be lost.

```
//Suggestion change parameter to domItem
var domObject
```

Your missing an error handler for when the parameter is not String.
when identifying the type use

```
<VARNAME>.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1] === "<TYPE>"
```

It's more efficient and handles custom types.

No need for all the logic in assignment of value attribute. Any dom Object can be made to have a value attribute. also not sure why you are setting the val versus the value.

```
domObject.attr('value',value);
```

**It is at this point that I can see your code could really use some documentation to help explain purpose**

If you are explicitly only wanting to set value on Input fields and set value as innerhtml on non input fields then yes the logic would be needed but could be simplified to ... as the value doesn't need to be detected to overwritten.

```
if (jQuery.inArray (domObject.prop('tagName').toLowerCase(), ['input' , 'select' , 'textarea']) >= 0) {
    domObject.attr('value',value);
} else {
    domObject.html( value );
}
```

No Idea why you are returning the domObject out.

So a quick rewrite without the return and keeping most of the logic adding error handling results in

```
/*jslint sloppy: true*/
/*global jQuery*/
function SetFieldValue(domString, value) {
    // as a safety function, check if a string representation of the domObjects was passed in and convert it to a jQuery object if it was
    var domObjects, index;
    //errorhandling
    if (domString === undefined || domString === null) {
        throw {error : "domString must have a value."};
    }
    if (domString.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1] !== "string") {
        if (domString.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1].match(/HTML[a-zA-Z]*Element/) === null) {
            throw {error : "domString expected to be String or domObjects"};
        }
    } else {
        if (jQuery(domString).length === 0) {
            throw {error : "domString does not resolve to a detectable domObjects."};
        }
    }
    //errorhandling

    //action
    if (domString.constructor.toString().match(/function (\w*)/)[1].match(/HTML[a-zA-Z]*Element/)) {
        //made as an array to normalize as jQuery returns an array allows code to be simplified
        domObjects = [domString];
    } else {
        domObjects = jQuery(domString);
    }

    //given that domObjects are an array need to step through the array
    for (index = domObjects.length - 1; index >= 0; index -= 1) {
        if (
            jQuery.inArray(
                domObjects[index].tagName.toLowerCase(),
                ['input', 'select', 'textarea']
            ) >= 0
        ) {
            if (domObjects[index].hasAttr('id')) {
                domObjects[index].val(value);
            } else {
                domObjects[index].attr('value', value);
            }
        } else {
            domObjects[index].html(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The above passes JSLint

Answer (score 0):

I know I didn't provide enough context for people to really dig into this problem but I have in the end solved it. What was the issue? Well it was @Kobi who first asked is the DOM element's ID unique ... to which I happily reported it was. And it had been but in fact that WAS the problem. Jesus. It's always the obvious things that you then go onto overlook that get you in trouble.

Anyway, thanks for your patience and help.